# Behavior of mailto: and onclick() on same element

Tags: javascript, user-experience, mailto

I use some server-side email obfuscation and do not want to put the full email address in a `mailto:` . Within the  element, I call a js function that fetches the email address from the server, and calls (another) `mailto:` link from without the js function.

I first kept the `href` empty (and I think it's the same when putting `#`), but when hoovering over the link, the status bar of the browser shows a link to the current page, and it looks just neater (and expected behavior) to show a `mailto:` link in the status bar, but just with the firstname of the person, and not with a valid email address.

HTML:

```
<a href="mailto:johny" onclick= "sendmail('jj'); return false;" title="Send email">
```

JS:

```
function sendmail(dest) {
var link = "";
fetch('/returnmailstring.php?dec='+code+'&input='+dest)
        .then(function(response) {
            response.text()
            .then(function(text) {
            link = text;
                if (link.length > 2) {
                    if(window.confirm('Send email to \n'+link+' ?')) {
                    window.location.href = link;
                    }
                }
            })
        })
}
```

So my question is whether it is acceptable to have a double/identical functionality, but using two different methods ?
I would have expected that maybe **two** "new mail" windows would be opened, or some other weird behavior, but everything actually works fine. But I cannot imagine that this is standards compliant, and that it would work fine in all browsers/devices?

A related question is about what should happen when user clicks on the link. I currently implemented a confirmation box, so user can choose `OK` to actually proceed with sending the email (using the default email client), or just copy the email address from the box (and paste into another mail client, e.g. gmail), and `Cancel` to return to the page. The alternative would be to skip the confirmation box and directly open the mail client after the click. Are there UX rules / standards to follow, or is it acceptable to use such confirmation box?

Comment: Unless you are sure that your users will **all** be using the default mail client installed on their devices (and not web-mail, like GMail), then `mailto:` is a bad idea. If you are using server-side code already, just set up a form to collect the email details and send the email via the server code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for your reply. We decided against a form, as this is too much hassle for potential clients/partners (we are a small B2B advisory firm); I mitigate the risk you mention by interposing (after the first click on the mail icon/email address) a confirmation box, where the email address is visible and can be copied as text, and then user can decide whether to actually send an email directly or not.